# Why is this simple jQueryUI code not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker

Here's the literal HTML markup I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

    <title>Register</title>

    <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>



<body>





<h2>Register</h2>



<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link rel="Stylesheet" href="../../Content/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" />



<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.date-selector').datepicker();

    }

</script>



<form action="/account/register" method="post">    <fieldset>

        <legend>UserModel</legend>
<div class="editor-label">

            <label for="DateOfBirth">Fecha de Nacimiento</label>

        </div>

        <div class="editor-field">

            <input class="date-selector" data-val="true" data-val-required="Debe escribir su fecha de nacimiento" id="DateOfBirth" name="DateOfBirth" type="text" value="1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM" />;

            <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="DateOfBirth" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

        </div>
```

Notice that the class date-selector is properly set, and also the javascript is properly hooking the event up. (I think).

How can I debug what's going wrong? Why doesn't the datepicker control pop up when I click on the date of birth input textbox?

Comment: @Pek: Where would these errors appear? I'm using Google Chrome to test my MVC3 application.

Comment: the error console: Right click any element -> "Inspect element" -> "Console"

Comment: Thanks, handy to know. I'm getting this: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input`. Is there a way to see what lines is firing the error?

Comment: Another helpful shortcut is Cmd + Option + J (Ctrl + Shift + J on Windows and Linux), which brings up the console and Developer Tools at once. That's the first place to check when your scripts aren't running as expected.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're missing a closing `);` at the end of your `$(document).ready()` handler:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.date-selector').datepicker();

});
```

For future reference, a good tool for checking your JavaScript before even running it is [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com).

Comment: He IS including jQuery core in the head, but the 2nd point is correct.

Comment: @OhCaN: Yep, the script tags were all over the place, thanks for the tip `:)`

Comment: That was it. I wish Visual Studio let me know of these syntax errors.

Comment: @Sergio: Agreed. I use a JSLint plugin for VS that you may find useful: http://jslint4vs2010.codeplex.com/